# Microsoft Graph API BadRequest Payload JSON format

Tags: html, json, powershell, rest, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using powershell but shouldn't really matter (I'm making a Graph API reset call)

I can send text just fine but as soon as I make an HTML Table to format the report I get

```
{"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Unable to read JSON request payload. Please ensure Content-Type header is set and payload is of valid JSON format.",
```

Comment: How are you making the table? ([mre])

Comment: Are you sure your HTML is properly encoded from the JSON point of view?

Comment: I have tried both simple | Convertto-html
and
foreach nested loop the create the string manually with <table><tr><td></td></tr> tags around appropriate object parts

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.